# using set to store unique values but what if more data in my array

Tags: vue.js

I was reading that I can use "SET" as a solution to remove duplicated values in an array. This works on a basic example, but what If I have more data in my array and also want this data to be found inside of my vue model as opposed to an external const, how do I make it work. I have 2 users that have the Job title dentist, it is supposed to bring back 2 unique values instead of all 3, what am I missing?

```js
//const numbers = [2, 3, 4, 4, 2, 3, 3, 4, 4, 5, 5, 6, 6, 7, 5, 32, 3, 4, 5]
  const People =[{Name:"Adam", Age:"22",Job:"Dentist"},{Name:"Bill", Age:"32",Job:"Teacher"},{Name:"Peter", Age:"42",Job:"Dentist"}]
new Vue({
  el: "#app",
  data: {
  
    numbers:[2, 3, 4, 4, 2, 3, 3, 4, 4, 5, 5, 6, 6, 7, 5, 32, 3, 4, 5],
    People:[{Name:"Adam", Age:"22",Job:"Dentist"},{Name:"Bill", Age:"32",Job:"Teacher"},{Name:"Peter", Age:"42",Job:"Dentist"}]
    
  },
  methods: {
   toggle: function(){
    alert("this");
   console.log([new Set(People)]);
   
    },
    mounted:function(){
    this.toggle();
    }
  }
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.17/vue.js"></script>
<div id="app">
  <h2>Todos:</h2>
  <button v-on:click="toggle">
  Click
  </button>
</div>
```

Comment: What output are you expecting?

Comment: @Psidom to display the unique Job names of the people. Should be Dentist, Teacher

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Extract the `Job` property from each object and then apply `Set`, i.e. `[...new Set(People.map(p => p.Job))]`

```js
const People =[{Name:"Adam", Age:"22",Job:"Dentist"},{Name:"Bill", Age:"32",Job:"Teacher"},{Name:"Peter", Age:"42",Job:"Dentist"}]

uniqueJobs = [...new Set(People.map(p => p.Job))]

console.log(uniqueJobs)
```

Demo with `vue.js`:

```js
new Vue({
  el: "#app",
  data: {
    numbers:[2, 3, 4, 4, 2, 3, 3, 4, 4, 5, 5, 6, 6, 7, 5, 32, 3, 4, 5],
    People:[{Name:"Adam", Age:"22",Job:"Dentist"},{Name:"Bill", Age:"32",Job:"Teacher"},{Name:"Peter", Age:"42",Job:"Dentist"}]
  },
  methods: {
    toggle: function(){
      console.log([...new Set(this.People.map(p => p.Job))]);
    },
    mounted:function(){
      this.toggle();
    }
  }
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.17/vue.js"></script>
<div id="app">
  <h2>Todos:</h2>
  <button v-on:click="toggle">
  Click
  </button>
</div>
```

Comment: what if my array is inside of the data-model?

Comment: access it with `this` keyword. `this.People`.

Comment: See the `vue` demo.

Comment: yes. it's called [spread operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_syntax). Here it's used to construct an array from a Set.